# Change data-src value of li

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i change data-src value of li? Im using lightgallery jquery plugin and want to change the data-src of the thumbnail

```
 <li id="imageThumb" data-src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Datas.Datas))">
            <img id="imageBig" src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Datas.Datas))" />
        </li>
```

this one works for the 
     img src but not the li

```
     document.getElementById("imageBig").src = oFREvent.target.result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a jquery tag so

using jquery

```
$('#imageThumb').data('src','newValue');
```

using javascript

```
document.getElementById("imageThumb").setAttribute('data-src', 'newVal');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/92/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using jquery then

```
$(function() {
    $("#imageThumb").data("src", "myValue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in javascript

```
document.getElementById("imageBig").setAttribute("data-src", oFREvent.target.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
$('#imageThumb').prop('data-src',oFREvent.target.result);
```